# cordova app with react does not resolve public assets

Tags: reactjs, cordova

I've got reactJs app which is deployed both as web and mobile app. 
Mobile app is based on Cordova (ver 7.1.0).

Everything works fine except local resources (ones located in www/subdirs)  are not found, despite they are there.
What is even more strange, some resources e.g. fonts are found, some- were found before (i18n files), but all of a sudden disappeared. Moreover, hardcoded in html images are found as well:

```
<img src='images/foo.png'/>
```

but exactly the same code being dynamically added with reactjs fails to reach the image.

Those resources which were found get resolved to proper url: file:///android_asset/www/subdir/resource.png

Those which are not- resolved to wrong path: file://subdir/resource.png

i tried both leading slash, no leading slash, setting html base tag- nothing

Does anybody have any idea what am i doing wrong?

thank you in advance

UPDATE:

here's security policy:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Comment: it might be a content security policy issue. please post your index.html file and compare with that one: https://github.com/sombriks/red-line-finance/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Silly me! the browser worked like a charm and resolved all the resources exactly as it's supposed to. The problem was caused by react router which upon app load changed location from host/context/section to host/section so all resources which had to be loaded after that were resolved to incorrect path: host/section/resource instead of host/context/resource.

The solution is either fix initial location switch or add  tab to the header